# How to insert two associated instances in to corresponding tables by using a Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I have two ActiveRecode model, **Car** and **User**, which has many-to-one association:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  ...
end
```

And, I have two tables in database, **cars** and **users**. **users** table has attribute **car_id**

I would like to have a migration which will insert a car instance to the **cars** table, **meanwhile**, there will be a user instance created which has the association with the car instance and will then be inserted to the **users** table. **How to do this in a migration?**

That's by run this migration, both the car instance and its associated user instance will be stored in the corresponding tables in database.

I am using Rails 3.

Comment: Do you have existing data hence the need to do this in a migration? Or are you attempting to seed data in your migration?

Comment: Well, I am attempting to seed data, BUT, I would like to implement this by using migration without using seed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example of migrations

```
class FillCarsAndUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    #if you have a Corresponding class for table 
    Corresponding.find(:all).each do |cor|
      #save data

      car = Car.create(...) #you may save old car id, if need "Car.create(:id => cor.car_id, ...)"
      User.create(:car_id => car.id, ...)
      ...
      User.create(:car_id => car.id, ...)
    end

  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
data = {'car1' => ['user1', 'user2'], 'car2' => ['user3'], 'car3' => ['user4']}
data.each do |car, users|
  car_obj = Car.create(:name => car)
  users.each do |user|
    User.create(:name => user, :car_id => car_obj.id)
  end
end
```